# Extensible formatting in Roslyn?

Tags: .net, code-formatting, roslyn

I have found the code formatting present in the Roslyn CTP quite lacking. But Dustin Campbell mentioned in [his talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/Roslyn) (around 42:00 mark) that:

> The actual formatting engine is also extensible. There's a rules engine there so you can add formatting rules and do custom stuff if you want to, as well.

But when looking at the actual code, I have found only the `Format(SyntaxNode)` extension method that internally uses an `internal` class `SyntaxFormatter`.

My question is: where is the extensibility? Is it present in the Roslyn CTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the release of the Roslyn June 2012 CTP, this extensibility is now available.  To invoke formatting, look at the `Format` extension method that is in Roslyn.Services.dll (don't forget to add a `using Roslyn.Services;`.

To expose your own formatting rules, try implementing the `Roslyn.Services.Formatting.IFormattingRule` interface.  Unfortunately, we don't have a sample of this yet, but feel free to ask questions for any issues you run into.

Comment: Looks like IFormattingRule is now internal to CodeAnalysis.Workspaces. Any suggestions for what mere consumers of this DLL should do to implement custom formatting rules for, say, code fixes?